# Identities similar to $\arctan(x)+\arctan(1/x)=\pi/2$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

The $\arctan(x)+\arctan(1/x)=\pi/2$ (for $x>0$) identity can be solved by taking the derivative of the left hand side, showing it is $0$, and then plugging in, say, $x=1$ to get its constant value $\pi/2$.

Are there any other (nontrivial) identities which can be solved similarly?  I am hoping for something a 1st semester Calculus student could solve... so not too difficult please!

Comment: "The $\arctan(x)+\arctan(1/x)=\pi/2$ (for $x>0$) identity can be solved by" noting that the two non-right angles in a right triangle add up to $90^\circ$.

Comment: There is a very important identity in the theory of elliptic integrals (which is not typically a part of 1st semester calculus for most students) which goes by the name [Legendre's Identity](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2009/08/pi-and-the-agm-legendres-identity.html?m=0). And it is proved in the same manner by showing derivative of an expression to be $0$.

Answer (score 7):

$$\arccos(x) + \arcsin(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

If we know $\sin'(x)=\cos(x)$ and $\cos'(x)=-\sin(x)$, then we can compute
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\big[\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)\big] = 0,
$$
to conclude $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)$ is constant.  Then plug in one value to get
$$
\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x) = 1
$$

Comment: But $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x) = 1$ comes directly by the definition by unit circle, I don't think  it is a good example to use derivatives to prove that.

Comment: It depends what you are doing.  The given example $\arctan(x)+\arctan(1/x)=\pi/2$ comes directly from looking at a right triangle.  For my answer: suppose $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are defined by certain power series.  Show that $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x) = 1$.  This may be one step in showing those functions defined by power series are indeed the previoulsy-known trig functions.

Comment: For a 1st semester Calculus student it seems a not good example to me, but it is only my point of view.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, many identities can be derived with similar derivative tricks (although arguably sometimes, the identities would have been used to derive the derivatives ...).

Examples:

> $\ln(ax) = \ln(a) + \ln(x)$

(where $a,x >0$, but we treat $a$ as a constant and $x$ as variable).

> $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x) =1.$

Further: If you notice that

> $\cos(2x) = \cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x)$ and
>
> $\sin(2x) = 2\cos(x)\sin(x)$

are derivatives of each other, you have to memorise only one of them.

Extending the question to inequalities, I let my calculus students prove the **AM-GM-inequality** (well, the basic case in two variables) by showing that for any $a > 0$, the function

> $f(x) = \frac12 (a+x) - \sqrt{ax}$ is increasing on $[a, \infty)$ (and $f(a) = 0$).

Answer (score 1):

If you want similar arctangent identities, then you can start off by noting how$$\arctan x+\arctan\left(\frac {1-x}{1+x}\right)=\frac {\pi}4$$Similarly$$\arctan x+\arctan\left(\frac {2-x}{1+2x}\right)=\arctan 2$$If we try replacing two with three, we get that$$\arctan x+\arctan\left(\frac {3-x}{1+3x}\right)=\arctan 3$$Therefore, it’s safe to say that$$\arctan x+\arctan\left(\frac {n-x}{1+nx}\right)=\arctan n$$

Comment: For a more rigorous proof, you can show that$$\arctan x+\arctan y=\arctan\left(\frac {x+y}{1-xy}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

The proof for $x>0$ can be obtained as follows

- let $\alpha=\arctan x \quad x\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}2\right)$

then

$$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}2-\alpha\right)=\frac1{\tan \alpha}=\frac1x \implies \frac{\pi}2-\alpha =\arctan \frac1x$$

Another similar identity is

$$\arcsin x + \arccos x=\frac{\pi}2 \quad \forall x\in[-1,1]$$

which can be proved by $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}2-\alpha\right)=\sin \alpha$.

Using derivatives we can prove some basic important inequalities as

- $\tan x\ge x\quad x\ge 0$
- $\sin x\le x\quad x\ge 0$
- $\sin x\ge x-x^3/6\quad x\ge 0$
- $\cos x \ge 1-\frac12 x^2$

and so on.

Comment: I understand the trig solutions, but want the students to use derivatives. Perhaps is there an identity which can be solved with derivatives, which can NOT be solved another simpler way(such as basic trig)?

Comment: Ah ok, using derivatives we can prove $\tan x\gex$, $\sin x\le x$, $\sin x\ge x-x^3/6$.